# CR XI Release 2 throws error in VS 2008 on Win 7 64-bit development machine

Tags: .net, crystal-reports, 64-bit

Our developers just got new Win 7 64-bit boxes.  We are using VS 2008 with Crystal Reports XI Release 2 service pack 6.  If we run a report in our app through VS 2008, we get the following error:

> An error has occurred while attempting to load the Crystal Reports
>   runtime.
>
> Either the Crystal Reports registry key permissions are insufficent or
>   the Crystal Reports runtime is not installed correctly.
>
> Please install the appropriate Crystal Reports redistutable
>   (CRRedist*.msi) containing the correct version of the Crystal Reports
>   runtime.

Our previous dev boxes were Win 7 32-bit, and posed no issues.

I've searched forums and found a few similar issues.  I've tried running the app as x86, installing a redist for 64-bit, and some forums said that you have to upgrade to CR 2008 because XI R2 doesn't support 64-bit.

Any help would be appreciated.  I'm going to keep searching in the meantime.

Comment: I had a similar issue, but not quite the same thing.  I ended up solving it by making sure the thread I used Crystal in was set to run with STA as the apartment state.  For some reason this only showed up in Windows 7 for me and not other OS's.  Maybe it'll work for you too.